# How to run react app installed on a azure linux based vm

Tags: reactjs

As like every time we run react app locally on our pc i just did the same process on a linux based vm of azure.
So what i did was :

Step:1 I just copied my react folder on vm at a particular location without the node modules .
Step:2 Then i  installed the dependencies using npm i that were already present in the projects package.json
Step:3 Then i started the the development server using npm run dev as it is an vite app.

[Screenshot for after running the development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esKri.png)

Now the app is running successfully . But now how to access the app on my local system . I am connected to mobile hotspot network i.e i am not connected to the VM's network .
Please answer this as soon as possible .